# how to delete nested <p> tag into other <p> tag but keeping the text into it. (HtmlAgilityPack)

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I am trying to format this input Html by using HtmlAgilityPack

```
<p>This is <p>a nested paragraph 1</p></p>
<p>This is <p>a nested paragraph 2</p></p>
```

I want to obtain as result:

```
<p>This is a nested paragraph 1</p>
<p>This is a nested paragraph 2</p>
```

deleting the nested paragraph tags.

the next function deletes all p tags, but I want to preserve them in case they do not have nested p tags.

```
public void CleanNestedP()
{
    var nodesP = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("p");    
    foreach (var item in nodesP.ToList())
    {
        var descendantsP = item.Descendants("p");
        if (descendantsP.Any())
        {
            var replacement = HtmlDocument.CreateTextNode(item.InnerText);
            item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(replacement, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Any HtmlAgilityPack expert out there? thank you.

Comment: Is CsQuery an option? (It's like a faster, modern HTMLAgilityPack)

Comment: it looks quite good, I didn't know it, I will have to take a look at it, but meanwhile it would still be nice to get a solution with HtmlAgilityPack, it should be possible. thanks.